# how to insert an array to JSONArray with rest assured

Tags: java, rest-assured

I want to insert the array with Rest Assured.
tokenUUIDs - is an array ( A variable that I defined in a previous step).
When I run the code - tokenUUIDs received a correct value But ArraytokenUUIDs have not received something good. He received : `[[Ljava.lang.String;@6fc0bbc6]`

**This is my Method:**

```
public static void releaseTokens(String[] tokenUUIDs )
{
    try{
        RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given();
        request.header("Content-Type", "application/json");

        JSONObject releaseTokens = new JSONObject();
        releaseTokens.put("partnerCode", commonOps.partnerCode);
        releaseTokens.put("apiAccessToken",commonOps.openAccessToken);
        releaseTokens.put("sessionUUID",SessionUUID);
        releaseTokens.put("taskUUID","TaskUUID");

        JSONArray ArraytokenUUIDs = new JSONArray();
        ArraytokenUUIDs.add(tokenUUIDs);


        releaseTokens.put("tokenUUIDs", ArraytokenUUIDs);


        request.body(releaseTokens.toJSONString());

        Response response = request.post((getData("APIenv") + "/api/sessions/releaseTokens.php"));
        int code = response.getStatusCode();

        Assert.assertEquals(code, 200);

        System.out.println("Status code for releaseTokens.php is" +code );

        ResponseBody bodyreleaseTokens = response.getBody();
        System.out.println("Body bodyreleaseTokens.php  " + bodyreleaseTokens.asString() );
        String statusbodyreleaseTokens = bodyreleaseTokens.asString();

        String status = response.getBody().jsonPath().getString("status");
        Assert.assertEquals(status, "OK");




        test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "bodyreleaseTokens is done" );
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {

        test.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "bodyreleaseTokens is not done");
        test.log(LogStatus.FAIL, e.getMessage());
        fail ("bodyreleaseTokens is not done");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add every token individually

```
  for (String s : tokenUUIDs){
      ArraytokenUUIDs.add(s);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
ArraytokenUUIDs.add(tokenUUIDs);
```

to

```java
for (String tokenUUID : tokenUUIDs) {
    ArraytokenUUIDs.add(tokenUUID);
}
```

---

Also consider that variables in java are named with lowercase first letter as a standard to avoid confusion with classes.

Comment: I received an error: The method put(List<String>) is undefined for the type JSONArray

Comment: Sorry, what library (and which version) are you using?

Comment: for Rest Assured?

Comment: For writing your json object

Comment: where can i find it?

Comment: You're using `JSONArray` class. I bet that has an import like `org.json.JSONArray`, which means you have a dependency on `org.json:json:<version>` on your gradle.build or pom.xml

Comment: I have only this in my pom.xml :
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

Comment: I've just updated my answer with the correct code implementation